# SQL - MATCH AGAINST with HAVING and COUNT()

Tags: sql, count, having-clause, match-against

does someone knows why this first query works and this second not?

first query (works):

```
SELECT *, 
       MATCH(username) AGAINST ('ergergergergergerg' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS _score
FROM (ci_users) HAVING _score > '0';
```

second query (not working):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), 
       MATCH(username) AGAINST ('ergergergergergerg' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS _score 
FROM (ci_users) HAVING _score > '0';
```

the first query returns exactly 24 rows, the second query returns 0 rows, while i just changed `*` to `COUNT(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one return every row that matches.

The second one contains an aggregation on id.

When aggregating, MySQL is smart enough (or should I say, stupid enough) to implicitly pick a any value from all fields that are queried, but not aggregated. So since you don't group by `score` and you don't aggregate `score`, MySQL will just return any of the scores of all records, of the intermediate result (before applying the `having` clause) including those that have a value of 0. So, this intermediate result may very well contain just a count of, say,  900 and a _score of 0. After filtering using `having`, no records remain.

Now, I would be happy to do a suggestion, but I cannot tell what you would actually want to be returned from that query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM
  (SELECT 
    id,
    MATCH(username) AGAINST ('ergergergergergerg' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS _score 
  FROM (ci_users) HAVING _score > '0') x;
```

Or even better:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM (ci_users) 
WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('ergergergergergerg' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > '0'
```

Comment: tells me tells me, i need to count all the results in the second query

Comment: Added two queries. I think both should work, in which case I would pick the second.

Comment: Just to confirm that the first query needs an alias because it's a derived table